# Javascript validation Problem

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

In my employee information page, i use the validation in the information page.

In that javascript regular expression,

```
var nameRegex = /^[(a-z)(A-Z)\s ]*$/;
```

This nameRegex match with my last and firstname.

```
} else if(!lastname.match(nameRegex)) {
```

For this one, special character are not allowed in last name.  It restrict all the special character apart from brackets as `( )`.  Why it ignore the bracket?  What is the  reason for that.  will you help me friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put parenthesis in your expression. It should be more like:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/
```

or

```
/^[A-Z\s]*$/i
```

(*`i` means case insensitive*)

If you put parenthesis inside a character class `[]`, they don't have any special meaning but are taken literally. Btw `\s` matches all whitespace characters, so you don't have to include a literal whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^[A-Za-z()\s]*$/
```